# React: Modify Parent State While Child Renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, purely-functional

Hooks are usually much nicer than classes, so I'm trying to pass down the ability to set a parent's state in a child of that parent using hooks. Specifically, I'm doing something like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {

    render = () => {
        return <>
           <Child useRegisterFoo={foo => {...;this.setState(foo);...;}} />
           { renderBasedOnRegister() }
           </>
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to define the child like this:

```
const Child = ({useRegisterFoo}) => {
     useRegisterFoo(1);
     useRegisterFoo(2);
}
```

I will define many such children, and thus having such a simple `useRegisterFoo` to register a particular property of the child would be really useful.

The problem is that react complains if it's done this way, understandably, as I'm modifying the state of the parent while the parent is being rendered. Specifically it says:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

What's a better approach at this problem? My main goal is to make the API from the perspective of the child as convenient as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the callbacks directly in the function body. This is an unintentional side-effect and shouldn't be done. Even in function components you still need to work with the component lifecycle.

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
> within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props
> and state.

The ***entire*** body of a function component is the "render" function. Use the `useEffect` hook to invoke these passed callbacks, or conditionally call them as part of an event handler.

Example:

Use an `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array to trigger the effect only once when the component mounts.

```
const Child = ({useRegisterFoo}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    useRegisterFoo(1);
    useRegisterFoo(2);
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency, effect triggered once on mount
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually did wrap all `setState` callbacks in a `useEffect` - all except for one, which I put in a `useState(() => ...setState)`, since it returned a value I needed. I didn't know they worked differently in terms of lifecycle. I've now separated them in parts that return a value, which I put in a `setState`, and parts that update the parent's state, which I put into `useEffect`. Works like a charm. Thanks!